# Issues With Excluding Results From Subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am attempting to retrieve a list of members (MEMBERS table) who have purchased (ARTRANS table) a product from one of three product categories (PRODUCTCATS table) during a specified period (a month) and then have not purchased a product from that category in the following period (month).

Both queries work by themselves but when I put them together I do not pull any results. PLEASE HELP!

```
 SELECT MEMBERS.lname
    , MEMBERS.fname
    , MEMBERS.email
    , PRODUCTS.scancode
    , PRODUCTS.description
    , ARTRANS.datetrans
    , ARTRANS.memid
    , ARTRANS.invoice
    , ARTRANSITEMS.price
    , ARTRANSITEMS.quantity
FROM PRODUCTS
INNER JOIN ARTRANSITEMS
    ON PRODUCTS.productid = ARTRANSITEMS.productid
INNER JOIN ARTRANS
    ON ARTRANSITEMS.transid = ARTRANS.transid
INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS
    ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid
INNER JOIN MEMBERS
    ON ARTRANS.memid = MEMBERS.memid
        AND NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT M2.memid
            FROM PRODUCTS AS P2
            INNER JOIN ARTRANSITEMS AS ATI
                ON P2.productid = ATI.productid
            INNER JOIN ARTRANS AS ART2
                ON ATI.transid = ART2.transid
            INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS AS PC2
                ON P2.productcatid = PC2.productcatid
            INNER JOIN MEMBERS AS M2
                ON ART2.memid = M2.memid
            WHERE (
                    P2.productcatid = '20'
                    OR P2.productcatid = '21'
                    OR P2.productcatid = '78'
                    )
                AND (ART2.datetrans BETWEEN DATEADD(month, 1, @rvMonthOneStart) AND DATEADD(month, 1, @rvMonthOneEnd))
            )
WHERE (
        PRODUCTS.productcatid = '20'
        OR PRODUCTS.productcatid = '21'
        OR PRODUCTS.productcatid = '78'
        )
    AND (ARTRANS.datetrans BETWEEN @rvMonthOneStart AND @rvMonthOneEnd)
```

Comment: You need a list of members (question)  or list of ARTRANSITEMS (query) ?

Comment: Can you show the  queries separated?

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
SELECT MEMBERS.lname, MEMBERS.fname, MEMBERS.email, PRODUCTS.scancode
      , PRODUCTS.description, ARTRANS.datetrans, ARTRANS.memid
      , ARTRANS.invoice, ARTRANSITEMS.price, ARTRANSITEMS.quantity
FROM PRODUCTS 
INNER JOIN ARTRANSITEMS ON PRODUCTS.productid = ARTRANSITEMS.productid 
INNER JOIN ARTRANS      ON ARTRANSITEMS.transid = ARTRANS.transid 
INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS  ON PRODUCTS.productcatid = PRODUCTCATS.productcatid 
INNER JOIN MEMBERS      ON ARTRANS.memid = MEMBERS.memid 
WHERE PRODUCTS.productcatid IN ('20' ,'21','78')
  AND (ARTRANS.datetrans BETWEEN @rvMonthOneStart AND @rvMonthOneEnd)
AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                FROM  PRODUCTS AS P2 
                INNER JOIN ARTRANSITEMS AS ATI  ON P2.productid = ATI.productid 
                INNER JOIN ARTRANS      AS ART2 ON ATI.transid = ART2.transid 
                INNER JOIN PRODUCTCATS  AS PC2  ON P2.productcatid = PC2.productcatid 
                INNER JOIN MEMBERS      AS M2   ON ART2.memid = M2.memid
                WHERE  PRODUCTS.productcatid IN ('20' ,'21','78') 
                  AND (ART2.datetrans BETWEEN DATEADD(month, 1, @rvMonthOneStart) AND DATEADD(month, 1, @rvMonthOneEnd))
                  AND M2.memid = MEMBERS.memid)
```